# Express server does not work on Vercel, works on localhost

Tags: express, deployment, server, vercel

I am building live chat app, and It is working, and I want to run it on vercel.
Everything is working fine on localhost, but it is not working on vercel or netlify.

This is my backend part folder structure.

[IMAGE1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RLIQh.png)

[IMAGE2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6PqIh.png)

Like everyone says, I made vercel.json file in root of folder and here it is code.

```
{
 "version": 2,
 "builds": [
  {
  "src": "../backend/server.js",
  "use": "@vercel/node"
  }
  ],
 "routes": [
 {
  "src": "/(.*)",
   "dest": "/"
  }
 ]
}
```

While finishing deploying on vercel, I added also env.variables.

But when deploying is finished, I always have this error.
https://backend-chat-app-rouge.vercel.app/

[ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tVsPV.png)

I don't have any errors or warnings on Biulding logs on Vercel.

I think problem might be realted to this from vercel.json :
"src": "../backend/server.js", because I need to import files like this:

**EDIT**

server.js file:

```
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 6001;
const dotenv = require(`dotenv`);
dotenv.config({ path: `./config.env` });
const app = require(`../backend/app`);
const mongoose = require(`mongoose`);

const DB = process.env.MONGO_URL.replace(`<PASSWORD>`, 
process.env.PASSWORD);

 mongoose
   .connect(DB, {})
   .then((con) => {
   console.log(`DB is connected`);
 })
 .catch((err) => {
 console.log(err);
 });

 const http = require("http");
 const server = http.createServer(app);
 const io = require("socket.io")(server);

 io.on("connection", (socket) => {
 console.log("A client connected");

 socket.on("message", (message) => {
 console.log("Received message:", message);
 io.emit("message", message);
   });
 });

 server.listen(PORT, () => {
 console.log(`Aplikacija radi na portu broj ${PORT}`);
 });
```

app.js file:

```
 const express = require(`express`);
 const app = express();
 const userRouter = require(`../backend/routes/userRoutes`);
 const chatRouter = require(`../backend/routes/ChatRoutes`);
 const messageRouter = require(`../backend/routes/MessageRoutes`);
 const cors = require(`cors`);
 const bodyParser = require(`body-parser`);

 //MIDLEWARE

 app.use(bodyParser.json());

 app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
 if (err instanceof SyntaxError && err.status === 400 && "body" in err) 
  {
  res.status(400).json({ status: "failed", message: "Invalid JSON 
  payload" });
  } else {
  next();
    }
  });

 app.use(
  cors({
     origin: "*",
     credentials: true,
  })
 );

 //ROUTES
 app.use(`/`, userRouter);
 app.use(`/chat`, chatRouter);
 app.use(`/messages`, messageRouter);

 module.exports = app;
```

Comment: Can you explain why you are importing files like ../backend/....   You should import files like `const app=require('./app.js')`

Answer (score 0):

in `vercel.json` file you have to add

```
"installCommand": "npm install"
```

and remove `../backend` from `src`
after making changes the `vercel.json` file looks like this

```
{
 "version": 2,
 "builds": [
  {
  "src": "./server.js",
  "use": "@vercel/node"
  }
  ],
 "routes": [
 {
  "src": "/(.*)",
   "dest": "/"
  }
 ],
"installCommand": "npm install"
}
```

finally make sure your server is listening on some **port(like 5000)** that you have added in your **env variable in vercel**

Comment: I tried this solution and it does not work.

Maybe the problem is in my env variables?

MONGO_URL=mongodb+srv://****************************
PASSWORD=********
PORT=3001
SECRET_STRING=***************
EXPIRES_IN=1d
EMAIL_USER=hazel.***********@ethereal.email
EMAIL_PASSWORD=**************
GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=./googleCloudJSON/************

I am wondering why is not anything working, like it is not even starting the server, I doubt on my server.js and app.js files so I will post it in full.

Comment: server.js file: